# Why does this XAML merged resource configuration fail at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following App.xaml:

```
<Application
    x:Class="Genisyss.V2.Client.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Genisyss.V2.Client"
    ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary
                    Source="Resources/ShellResources.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <local:AppBootstrapper
                        x:Key="bootstrapper" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

ShellResources.xaml looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    x:Class="Genisyss.V2.Client.Resources.ShellResources"
    x:ClassModifier="public">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <!-- EXTERNAL RESOURCES -->
        <ResourceDictionary
            Source="/Teton.Wpf;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary
            Source="Images.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <!-- controls and templates defined, etc -->

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Configured this way, the program fails at runtime with "resource not found" or "xaml parse exception".

If I change App.xaml to ALSO include external resources, like this:

```
<Application
    x:Class="Genisyss.V2.Client.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Genisyss.V2.Client"
    ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

                <!-- NOTE ADDITION OF EXTERNAL RESOURCES -->
                <ResourceDictionary
                    Source="/Teton.Wpf;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />

                <ResourceDictionary
                    Source="Resources/ShellResources.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <local:AppBootstrapper
                        x:Key="bootstrapper" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Now my program finds the resources at runtime and runs without error. What gives with this? I thought the point of merged resources was ACTUALLY TO MERGE THE RESOURCES, so that you didn't need to declare them in two places.

**EDIT**

Changed the Source property in ShellResources.xaml to be an absolute pack uri:

```
pack://application:,,,/Teton.Wpf;component/Themes/Generic.xaml
```

But this made no difference.

Comment: Note sure but it might be related about the search strategy being different for the app. regarding the `Source` property, try to reference them using an absolute URI : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed it in ShellResources.xaml to be `pack://application:,,,/Teton.Wpf;component/Themes/Generic.xaml`... but no difference.

Comment: I've just tried a similar scenario here but it's fine, I don't have a boot strapper type though. We need to know what's causing the error, comment the lines and try to find out who's the culprit.

Comment: My suspicion is that it's related to the lack of a StartupUri in App.xaml. As you noted, I'm using a bootstrapper instead. However, I did verify that `InitializeComponent()` is being called in App.xaml.cs. The error is happening in one of the custom controls from the Teton.Wpf dll rather than one of the local controls, if that provides any hints or a-ha type alarm bells.

Comment: You should post a complete code sample here so people can find out, it might work OOB though ... Have you tried `Options, Debugging, Output Window, WPF Trace settings, Resource dictionnaries`, it might give you a hint.

Comment: @Aybe, thanks for your comments. I have discovered the subtleties of custom styles for standard controls in Generic.xaml and will be posting an answer as to why this happened. The bug was my fault (as usual) but it can be very tricky to identify.

Answer (score 0):

This bug showed up because of the order that things need to be defined in a resource file. I have a WPF controls project that defines some custom controls AND overrides the default styles of several built-in controls.

To make a long story short, I had resources that were defined further down in the `Generic.xaml` file, and they were being accessed further up - that's a no-no. Resources are apparently parsed only once, in a strict top-down fashion. I was under the impression that they were parsed in a two-or-more pass manner just like normal c# source code.

To avoid this happening, here is a suggested way to lay out your `Generic.xaml` in a WPF Controls project:

```
<!-- Shared resources like brushes and colors -->
<!-- DEFAULT control styles, e.g. <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"... -->
<!-- Control styles for custom controls that are defined in your project -->
```

Thanks to @Aybe for pushing me to dig deeper on this.